# How to fit all the views inside android phone screen?

Tags: android

I am using relative view with the all the child views indside it. But the problem is that when I am running the app on my android device having android 6.0.1, then the textview is half cutted at the bottom of the device screen. Tell me either how to fit all he contents on the screen or help me making the view scrollable. below is the code. Kindly help me as I am a beginner in Android

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/apple" />

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/applemainimg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/logo"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-200dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/applemain" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="391dp"
        android:layout_height="215dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/applemainimg"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-233dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
        Amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi. 
        Mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant. 
        Elit eget gravida cum sociis. Laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac. 
        Quis auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit. Quis eleifend quam adipiscing 
        vitae proin sagittis nisl. 
        Commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed. Vel facilisis volutpat est 
        velit egestas dui id. 
        Mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant."
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


     </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It would be great to share the screenshot here, for more responses

Comment: To make a layout scrollable just wrap it in a scrollview.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo Scroll bar is not displaying or working even after wrapping in scroll view. Kindly help by running this code on your machine.

Comment: It's not being displayed because there's nothing to scroll. Your views probably fit fine on the screen. The only reason why the text is being cut off is because your textview has a set height instead of wrapping its contents.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo Ya you're right. There was a mistake with my text view height. Now I am able to scroll the views. Looking forward for your help when I get stuck again coz I have started learning Android last week.

Comment: good luck! I'll be happy to help again if I can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/applemainimg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/logo"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="391dp"
        android:layout_height="215dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/applemainimg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    Amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi.
    Mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant.
    Elit eget gravida cum sociis. Laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac.
    Quis auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit. Quis eleifend quam adipiscing
    vitae proin sagittis nisl.
    Commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed. Vel facilisis volutpat est
    velit egestas dui id.
    Mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant."
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Pay attention to the height of the Relativelayout it needs to wrap_content and not match_parent

Instead of using `android:layout_alignBottom` you need to use `android:layout_below` also I don't recommend you to use such big margins if you need to support multiple screen sizes. If you have a more complex layout I would rather use `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: The text inside the textview is still not displaying full. Half of the text are still cutted out. The scroll bar is also not functioning. Kindly help me to fit all the views inside the phone screen.

Comment: Ya now I understood your suggestion and would try to implement in future but currently i am not practising constraint layout. Looking forward for your help during my whole android journey:)

Comment: I will gladly help you next time, if this answer helped you please accept the answer (there is an option left of the answer) thank you